# Dynamically setting pageno and maxrow to datapager control using a stored procedure

Tags: asp.net

I have a ListView and I am paging with a DataPager.i am using a stored procedure to return the paged Data.Stored procedure returns the total no of rows as out paramater.

my stored procedure is

```
crate procedure [dbo].[Sp_ProductList]
@Id int,
@Country int,
@state int,
@City int,
@Group int,
@pageno int,
@pageCount int out
as begin
--custom search
end
```

in my List view  layout is

```
  <asp:ListView ID="LstCatalogue" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LstCatalogue_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <LayoutTemplate>
<div id="productContent" class="center_Productcontent">
                <div runat="server" id="ItemPlaceholder"></li>
            </div>
    <div class="Pager">
        <asp:DataPager ID="pgrUpper" runat="server" PageSize="9" PagedControlID="LstCatalogue">
             <Fields>
             <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonCssClass="command" FirstPageText="First" PreviousPageText="Previous" RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true" RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="true"  ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowNextPageButton="false" ShowLastPageButton="false"  ShowPreviousPageButton="true" />
             <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10" NumericButtonCssClass="command" CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current" NextPreviousButtonCssClass="command" RenderNonBreakingSpacesBetweenControls="true" />
             <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonCssClass="command" NextPageText="Next" LastPageText="Last" RenderDisabledButtonsAsLabels="true" ShowFirstPageButton="false" ShowPreviousPageButton="false" ShowNextPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true" />
        </Fields>
      </asp:DataPager>
            </div>


        </LayoutTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

My problem is how can i set paging in datapager.based on the paged data from the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

you can  do like this..... in datapager controls.....

```
    <asp:DataPager ID="dataPagerNumeric" 
                 runat="server" PageSize="5">
                   <Fields>
                        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="5" 
                        NumericButtonCssClass="numeric_button" 
                        CurrentPageLabelCssClass="current_page"
                                        NextPreviousButtonCssClass="next_button" />
                   </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
              <td colspan="4" class="number_of_record">
                  <asp:DataPager ID="dataPageDisplayNumberOfPages" 
                  runat="server" PageSize="5">
                    <Fields>
                           <asp:TemplatePagerField>
                                <PagerTemplate>
                                     <span style="color: Black;">Records:
                                           <%# Container.StartRowIndex >= 0 ? 
                                           (Container.StartRowIndex + 1) : 0 %> -
                                           <%# (Container.StartRowIndex + 
                    Container.PageSize) 
                                           > Container.TotalRowCount ? 
                    Container.TotalRowCount : 
                                           (Container.StartRowIndex + 
                    Container.PageSize)%> of
                                           <%# Container.TotalRowCount %>
                                                </span>
                                            </PagerTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplatePagerField>
                                    </Fields>
                                </asp:DataPager>
                            </td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
```

would you pls go through this link [For more Info](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PagingWithListView.aspx)

I hope it will helps you...